# Live Template not working in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, live-templates

Hope you have worked with Live Templates which is given by Android by default.

Like:

```
Generate debug log statement: "logd"+TAB
Generate error log statement: "loge"+TAB
Generate info log statement: "logi"+TAB
Generate TAG declaration: "logt"+TAB
Generate parameter logging: "logm"+TAB
Generate method return log: "logr"+TAB
```

[image]

### Which it is not available in **KOTLIN**?

Is it not available in **Android Studio 3.0 Canary Version**?

Comment: Accepted answer as of writing this comment is not the best way to reuse templates.

Comment: Seems like Android Studio's Kotlin "out-of-the-box" support is still in development

Comment: Just created the templates as described by [Leo Droidcoder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46152625/4540114) (@Leo Droidcoder Thanks!) and uploaded them to [Github](https://github.com/TobiasUhmann/android-studio-log-templates-for-kotlin). Simply download the .jar and import it in Android Studio via 'File > Import Settings...'

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yet not added log template in **Kotlin Live templates section** in Android Studio.

**Settings -> Editor -> Live Templates -> Kotlin** for **kotlin** templates.

[image: kotlin templates]

**Settings -> Editor -> Live Templates -> AndroidLog** for **AndroidLog**  templates

[image: AndroidLog templates].

*So you can't get the same AndroidLog templates in Kotlin code.*

So now **Question** is *How to use same Log Functions using templates in Kotlin*?

**Ans:** You can add same Log templates (AndroidLog Templates) in **Kotlin Templates section** in Android studio as below example.

[image: Kotlin Templates section]

Then It will be available in your Kotlin code!

[image: Kotlin loge]

I hope in this way you can get an advantage of Log functions templates in Kotlin.

Comment: Excellent and clear explanations. However, whatever template I add under kotlin, never does Android Studio make it work for me as it would with Java. Indeed, whenever I start writing `log` it suggests logarithm functions... though, there are no templates for those. I am running Android Studio 3.5. Thanks for the help ! I have tried with different names, no suggestions at all. And I also tried by restarting AS.

Answer (score 38):

Here is the step-by-step guide:

**Firstly**, Copy and paste AndroidLog templates to Kotlin (Just select them and use CMD+C, CMD+V (or Ctrl+C, Ctrl+V)
**Secondly**, You have to adjust them manually:

1. **logd (loge, logv and others)** 
   Select the logd item and press "Edit variables" 
   [image]

Change expression to: kotlinMethodName()
[image]

Also, remove `;` from the end of the template, as you don't need it in Kotlin.

Now your method name will be shown correctly

2. **logt**

This one is a bit trickier.
**Solution 1: TAG = class name.**

Template text :

```
private val TAG = "$className$"
```

Edit variables -> Expression:

```
groovyScript("_1.take(Math.min(23, _1.length()));", kotlinClassName())
```

**Solution 2: TAG = file name** (can be used inside Companion)

Template text :

```
private const val TAG = "$className$"
```

or:

```
companion object {
    private const val TAG = "$className$"
}
```

Edit variables -> Expression:

```
groovyScript("_1.take(Math.min(23, _1.length()));", fileNameWithoutExtension())
```

Comment: Thanks @Leo for sharing a new solution. As you said, It is much simpler.

Answer (score 13):

You don't need to copy paste anything as mentioned in the other answers. Locate the **"Applicable in *"** text in the **Live Templates** section in Android Studio - clicking on "Change" button gives a list of all scopes. Choose Kotlin (or one of it's child nodes) and apply. Note that some statements from Java will not work in Kotlin (like the ones using static keyword) - It's better to create a new template for those, rather than editing the existing one.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

[Here](https://github.com/kirtan403/android-studio-live-templates) is the repository which contains all the templates for Android-Kotlin.

All you need to do this is download the repository, copy the [templates](https://github.com/kirtan403/android-studio-live-templates/tree/master/templates) directory and paste in your Android Studio config folder.

The config folder for your Android Studio can be found at

```
Windows: C:\Users\%userName%\.AndroidStudio<version>\config\templates
Linux: ~AndroidStudio<version>/config/templates
macOS: ~/Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio<version>/templates
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the combination of all good answers by @pRaNaY @Leo and @Jaguar with **bonus** of TAG-free and variable-ready usage (no need to type "${}")

**Template text:** android.util.Log.d("$className$", "$methodName$  $$$contents$")

**Applicable in** Kotlin: top-level, statement, class, expression

**variable expressions** can be found in dropdown menu

[here you can see whole picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ratxf.png)

Answer (score 0):

For logt the above two answers works but additionally need to add "define" as "class"

[image]